# Opening PopUp in JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to open a popup in JS function but its not working

*Here is the* **JS** *function*

```
function verifyUser(user,pwd)
    {
    var name = user;
     var paswd = pwd;
    if(name === 'user' || paswd === '123')
     {
      $( "#pwdpopup" ).popup('close');
      $( "#aboutPopup" ).popup('open');

     }
     else
     {
     alert('Incorrect User Name or Password');
     }
    }
```

*and here is the* **HTML**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="pwdpopup">
   <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Authentication</h1>
   </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <label for="uname">User Name </label> <input type="text" id="uname" />
        <label for="pswd" >Password </label><input type="password" id="pswd" />
         <button onClick="verifyUser(uname.value,pswd.value);">Verify</button>
      </div>
 </div>


 <div data-role="popup" id="aboutPopup">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>About Application</h1>
     </div>
   <div data-role="content">
        <div id="version">
        </div>
        <div id="resDate">
        </div> 
       <div id="release">
       </div> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

everything works fine the pwdpopup closes as well but the other popup is not opening

Comment: can u make a demo in fiddle?

Comment: Is the popup() function a native javascript funciton? If not, where is it?

Comment: @lennon626 : no its basically a jQuery Mobile popup and this html page is opened in a Android Device WebView

Comment: and popup() is a native function

Comment: Try direct " $( "#pwdpopup" ).popup('close'); $( "#aboutPopup" ).popup('open');" to run in console ...Is it working?

Comment: I see. It's a jquery helper method. The only thing I see with your code is you don't need to use those variables. user and pwd are essentially variables. But that shouldn't affect what you're trying to accomplish. A jsfiddle might help.

Comment: Actually, it looks like jsfiddle doesn't include jquery mobile library, so maybe jsbin?

Comment: tried to put it in jsFiddle but not working  . ..

Comment: I tried fiddle and jsbin and I can't seem to get it to work. The console keeps saying that undefined is not a function. Presumably this is because of the library you're using. The 'popup' method isn't being recognized. Back to the drawing board. Now i have to figure this out because it's pissing me off ;)

Comment: To use the jquery mobile library, you also need to include the jquery library, as the mobile one is dependent on that. DO you have both libraries? If you don't, your functions will not work.

Comment: yes i have included both libraries...

Comment: even i have use popup('close') 3 times in this page and it worked properly , even in this function it closes the dialog . .

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the conditional "||", and try with "&&", I imagine is the comparison you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the jquery library along with the jquery mobile library? If not, the functions aren't going to work because the libraries are dependent on each other. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, and the console just keeps saying that your functions aren't defined. So I'm guessing this is the issue you're having.